# How to put a " inside of a variable python

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a encryption program recently, and I cant quite figure out how to place double quotes inside a variable, in this case 'alphabet'. Currently I have every character I need except for " and a tab key, keep in mind I'm just a beginner and help  would be appreciated. - Thanks!

```
while True:
    plaintext = input('Enter messege: ')
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,!?#@$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|\:;`~<>/ '" 
    key = not telling you what I am
    cipher = ''
    for c in plaintext:
       if c in alphabet:
            cipher += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c)+key)%(len(alphabet))]

    print ('your encrypted message is: ' + cipher)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\"`

Sample:

```
print ("Hello \"")
```

Output:

```
Hello "
```

Comment: I would love some help with another question I have posted under my account, who knows maybe you can answer it?